# Django: Get queryset after a certain ID

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I currently have an Event model where objects are sorted by event_time (UTC UNIX timestamp) stored as a Django IntergerField in ASC order. Because I'm not sorting by ID, this creates a problem when it comes to paging, especially with a queryset that is constantly growing. Here is my event model:

```
# models.py

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_time = models.IntegerField(default= 0, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now for my views.py

```
# views.py    

def events_view(request):
    # range of queryset sent in request params

    last_event_id = int(request.GET.get('last_event_id'))
    start_time = int(request.GET.get('start_time'))
    end_time = int(request.GET.get('end_time'))

    if last_event_id == 0:
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(event_time__gte = start_time,
                         event_time__lte = end_time).order_by('event_time')[:10]

    else:
        '''This is the part I'm having trouble with,
           when the client requests the second page,
           they will send the same start_time and event_time
           as before but also send the event id of the last 
           event object from the first page. I need 
           to be able to get the next 10 objects in the 
           queryset after that event ID.'''

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Since I'm ordering by event_time, I need something unique to page the queryset. I need to make sure when the user requests the next page that they don't see the same objects that we're already sent from the previous page. How can I go about getting those next 10 rows?

Just to be clear, I can't use id__gte, lte, gt, lt. The queryset is not ordered based on ID, it is ordered based on event_time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use Django Pagination to achieve that.**

This will remove the if-else part in your code and you will not need to worry about the `last_event_id` then. Just send the all the `queryset` objects to the `Paginator` and the number of items you’d like to have on each page, it will give you methods for accessing the items for each page.

To get the list of objects for a particular page, just send an extra parameter `page_no` in the request.

Try this:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def events_view(request):
    # range of queryset sent in request params

    start_time = int(request.GET.get('start_time'))
    end_time = int(request.GET.get('end_time'))
    page_no = int(request.GET.get('page_no', 1))

    objects = Event.objects.filter(event_time__gte = start_time,
                         event_time__lte = end_time).order_by('event_time')
    p = Paginator(objects, 10)

    requested_page = p.page(page_no)
    requested_objects_list = requested_page.object_list #  required objects list

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I can't use id__gte, gt, lte, or lt. Those will only give me events that have an id greater than the last_event_id, meaning I'll miss some objects. I just need the next set of objects that come after that id, not greater than that id.

Comment: But isn't that what you want to get the next 10 objects after that event_id. Please give an example of an id which you might miss, that might help further.

Comment: Yes but events aren't ordered based on ID, they are ordered based on event_time. For example, if last_event_id = 9 for an event with event_time today at 2:00pm, I can still have an event with an id less than 9 for tomorrow at 5:00 pm. Do you see my dilemma?

Comment: Why don't you try a different approach like using `Paginator` for it.

Comment: Thx Rahul, I have thought about using Paginator before, which would work if the queryset doesn't change. However this queryset is always growing. By the time the user views a page, the contents of that page have been shifted, meaning when they access the next page, they might see content they have already seen before. Is there perhaps a raw SQL solution to this problem? Perhaps this is beyond the scope of what Django can do.

Comment: The dynamic nature of the querysets is always going to be a problem. Is the `id` field always increasing as in next `id` would always be greater than the previous when it is created?

Comment: Yes, for every new Event object, it's ID will be greater by 1 than the previous Event object. If I ordered by ID, I wouldn't have a problem at all. But the problem is event_time. Regardless of ID, an event object can be assigned any event_time. I can only use the ID to differentiate one event object to another, I was hoping to use the ID to page through the results of the growing queryset.

Comment: Getting the same object is always going to be there. You would have to keep track when the request came and what all objects he would have seen  and then not show those objects. You can add another field in `order_by` to get the latest objects created sorted by the event time by a queryset like `.order_by('event_time', '-id')`. Since `id` and `created` is always increasing, you can also do `.order_by('event_time', '-created')`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, what do you think about the idea of perhaps caching the entire queryset in memcacheD? When the user requests the first page, I can grab the pk values_list of the entire queryset, using celery and fire off a background task to store the list at a key. When the user requests the second page, I'll simply make a call to memcached with that key, and grab the next set of ids. What do you think of this approach? It's costly, but I think this is the most effective solution.

Comment: Yes, that would be a little costly. You can set the `id`s list requested in the session and then in the next request, use that session to get the next list of ids.

Comment: I really like that approach, thanks for you time Rahul, appreciate you helping me walk through the scenario.